# How can I add codpen JS and AJax to my one wordpress page

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, integration-testing

I just found a nice slider on codepen and want to integrate into my wp homepage (single page).

I have tried to export the Codepen slider and inject the inline JS and CSS.
to the header using custom header code plugin and HTML code in the body.but got a conflict with other codes I already have on the website.

My question is How Can I make that JS inline code affect only one DIV/ ID.

Thank you

Comment: Put the JS in a separate file and [enqueue](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) it in your theme's `functions.php`

Comment: Thank you APAD for your response. Can you link me with tutorial how to do that? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rely on inline scripts. Save them as separate files (hicham-slider.css/js) and store them somewhere on your site (probably `/wp-content/themes/ACTIVETHEME/css/` and `/wp-content/themes/ACTIVETHEME/js/`, create those directories if they don't exist.

Then you'll need to [enqueue](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) them with your functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hicham_scripts' );
function hicham_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'hicham-slider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/css/hicham-slider.css', [], '1.0' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'hicham-slider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/hicham-slider.js', ['jquery'], '1.0', true );
}
```

Then put the HTML in a Custom HTML widget or in the html/text editor of a page or post.

If the slider doesn't rely on jQuery, turn the `['jquery']` into `[]` instead. Read more about properly enqueueing with [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) and [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)